# replace special characters with null while reading from DB2 table

Tags: database, db2, special-characters, regexp-replace

I need to replace special characters like "VT" (Vertical tab), new line, carriage return etc while reading from the DB2 table with null value.

I see that REGEXP_REPLACE function is not working in DB2 or not taking it as a function in the select clause.

Is there any way to replace all special characters in general with null ?

Comment: Please edit your question, to specify the exact full error message ("not working"  is not adequate as it tells us nothing)  Show also your SQL that causes the error, and tag your Db2 server platform (z/os,  i-series,  linux/unix/windows) and its version.

Answer (score 2):

The `REGEXP` functions accept Unicode character classes, and also ranges of Unicode code-points.

You might need to define what you class as a "Special Character". E.g. is `£` a special character? What about ?

If you take the Unicode Definition of "Control" characters at the set you want to remove, then you could use this to remove them

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(your_column, '[\p{Control}]*','')
```

If you want to remove say all characters apart from e.g. "plain" printable 7-bit ASCII equivalents, you could use this

```
 REGEXP_EXTRACT(your_column,'[^\u0020-\u007E]+','')
```

This remove every character that is not between `U+0020 SPACE` and `U+007E TILDE` in Unicode. I.e. it will leave everything that is Basic Latin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Basic_Latin  but all other code-points will be removed (including e.g. `£`, `€`, `À` and )

Comment: Hello Paul, while using function REGEXP_EXTRACT i am getting error                                  440:  SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "REGEXP_REPLACE" of type "" having compatible arguments was found.  SQLSTATE=42884.

Comment: Have you checked if you are using a version of Db2 that includes that function? It was new in Db2 (for LUW) 11.1 for example

Comment: You should edit your post to say what version you are using

Answer (score 0):

try with x'code ascii' (cf: x'OA' for LF), it work for me on DB2 LUW 11.5

```
db2 => select 'AE'||x'0A'||'MN' from sysibm.sysdummy1;

1
-----  
AE 
MN
```

replace LF with : -

```
db2 => select REGEXP_REPLACE('AE'||x'0A'||'MN',x'0A','-') from sysibm.sysdummy1;

1
-----------
AE-MN
```